# How to access unity theme details programmatically?

Tags: unity, themes, configuration

What is the best approach to find about the details of theme which is currently in use in Unity DE? example : icons, colors ...
I don't know much about the Unity configurations and I assume that there must be some configuration option stored somewhere which defines options for a custom Unity DE theme for example path to a directory which Icons or Css files are stored ( and to parse those configuration files programmatically).

Thanks for your time.